# How to provide credentials for Digest Authentication in Silverlight 5 and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, authentication, silverlight-5.0

We currently have a Silverlight 5 Out-of-browser application calling a number of WCF webservices.

I wish to secure these services using Digest authentication, however I'm failing to get Silverlight to actually submit the credentials.

```
// step one - find and remove default endpoint behavior 
        var defaultCredentials =        channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
        channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials);

        // step two - instantiate your credentials
        ClientCredentials loginCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
        loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myusername";
        loginCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypassword";

        // step three - set that as new endpoint behavior on factory
        channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loginCredentials); //add required ones
```

When I use this code, the client first makes and anonymous request, the server responds with a 401 result code, and Silverlight then prompts me for credentials.

In other parts of the application I make a WebRequest to a Rest service, and in this instance I can supply credentials for Digest authentication and it works.

What is even more strange, is that if I first make a WebRequest with credentials, Silverlight seems to cache those credentials and uses them for the WCF call. But after a few seconds those credentials become invalid, and subsequent WCF calls present the prompt again.

Is there any way to use Digest authentication with WCF in Silverlight 5?